# It's too easy? It's too easy!

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking

> I'm asked by my University Professor, Mandy, to come and see her in
>   her office after class.  "Somethin' wrong?" I keep thinking when I
>   head to her office.
>
> "You are elected to be our Math club's consultant and I can see why. 
>   However," as Mandy continues, "I will have you solve this question.
>   If you fail to do so, I'll find somebody to take your place."
>
> "Fair enough." I think.

```
And here's the question:    

e + f + 20 = 2  
c + d + 88 = 5  
c + d + e + f = ?
```

> Before I could write down -101 as the answer, Mandy mentioned the
>   answer is not -101!
>
> As I struggle, another student who passed by managed to see the question
>   and said "It is too easy"
>
> "Correct." said Mandy and the student became the Club's consultant
>   instead.

What is the correct answer and, what happened?

Also, could you find all the hidden references in the question?

EDIT: I have made a mistake on the question posted and it's been edited.  Unsure if it violate the rule I will go ahead and accept the correct answer

Comment: are all the grammar mistakes intentional?

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that the student was chosen for the consultancy position based on no more nor less information than is provided above?

Comment: omgomgomgomg I put a+b+c+d instead of b+c+d omgomgomg I will close this question

Comment: @Alex I'm really confused... I see that originally the question said `a+b+c+d=?` and that was edited to say `a+b+c=?` but your previous comment suggests you edited it to `b+c+d=?` what is the correct question supposed to be?

Comment: The way you've edited this makes -100 an arbitrary answer, c can equal anything. Maybe remove d entirely?

Comment: A messed up question followed by a messed up edit, ah...  (edited)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is

> 2 ("Two, easy!")
>  The answer is the number of circles (closed loops) in each problem - 2 in the first ('e', and the '0' of 20), 5 in the second ('d', and two each in the '8's), 2 in the third ('d' and 'e').

Comment: What about the closed loop of the 'a' in the third line?

Comment: @RobWatts yeah I missed this completely when I edited it to clean it up a little.

Comment: Thank you! Fixed it! I was overlyexcited to be the first to answer!

Comment: But then if it's three in the third, it's not two.

Comment: you're correct somehow after I put up my question incorrectly...  I will accept your answer if I could, need some SE admin's assist =.=

Answer (score 2):

The answer is

> **-100**
>
> Through rearrangement we get
> a + b = -17
> c + d = -83
> therefore a + b + c + d = -17 + -83 = -100
>
>  Mandy was testing his confidence and since he hesitated to give the correct answer in the face of adversity she chose a different student who was more confident.